# CUDA synchronize function fails during long running kernel

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I'm using PyCuda to run a kernel that is expected to take at least two hours to complete, but it is failing after around one hour with the simple error of:

`pycuda._driver.Error: cuCtxSynchronize failed: unknown error`

I'm using Windows, and I added the registry key TdrDelay and set it to 120000000 to ensure that Windows is not timing out my kernel.

This error doesn't happen when I adjust the parameters of the kernel so it is expected to complete in about 30 minutes. Why could the synchronize call be failing after the kernel has run for a long time?

Could my graphics card be overheating and preemptively terminating the kernel? Could there be a CUDA setting that terminates a kernel if it runs for too long? Could running the kernel in NVidia Visual Profiler help figure out what the problem might be?

Comment: my guess would be that you are still hitting a tdr timeout.   I'm not sure that your setting does what you think it does.  Yes, your graphics card could be overheating, but this isn't usually possible (the GPU should have a mechanism to manage temperature, regardless of load).  You can monitor temperatures with `nvidia-smi`.  There are no CUDA settings that terminate a long-running kernel (other than the aforementioned windows WDDM TDR).  I doubt  the visual profiler will shed any useful light on this.

Comment: The TdrDelay definitely does something, because before I added that key my kernel was timing out after two seconds. Maybe TdrDelay has some maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my long running kernel to complete without error by adding the registry key "TdrLevel" alongside "TdrDelay" and setting its value to 0.

Comment: Can you specify where and what you exactly set? did you set both level and delay to 0?

Comment: @NoBlockhit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers is where those two keys should be added. This link has info on what those keys do: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-tdr-values-and-edit-registry-keys/84a9b079-6048-4968-982a-e648152c17fd